# Displaying user input via list

Tags: java, list, spring-mvc, vaadin, user-input

I am using Vaadin and Spring and I want to display email address when I click on add email button along with edit and delete buttons next to email address. You can see how it looks for Phone. How can I do it using List ?

[image: Here is the image]

This is code for Email Layout

```
 private void createEmailLayout()
    {

        emailLayout = new VerticalLayout();
        emailLayout.setMargin(false);
        emailLineLayout = new GridLayout(3, 1);
        emailLineLayout.setSpacing(true);

        Button emailButton = getButton("Add Email");
        emailButton.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener()
        {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = -817258593606002344L;

            @Override
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event)
            {
                PersonWindow personDialog = new PersonWindow("Add Email", new DialogWindowListener<Person>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void dialogConfirmed(Person email)
                    { 

                        person.setEmail(email.getEmail());           

                       refreshEmailList();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void dialogClosed(boolean confirmed)
                    {
                    }
                });

                CcptUI.getCurrent().addWindow(personDialog);

            }
        });

        emailLayout.addComponents(emailLineLayout, emailButton);

    }
```

Comment: What you are referring to with List? In Vaadin there is no component named List. If in your use the list of e-mail addresses is fairly small, using Grid component is probably overkill. In that case I would just create e.g. GridLayout or VerticalLayout and add the content to layout.

Comment: What do you want to use your list for? Do you want to read the elements out of a list and create the email layouts based on them?

Comment: @TatuLund Yes I know there is no component in Vaadin names List. I want it like when I click on Add Email, it opens a small window where I enter email address and when I click on OK button, it should be display below first email. Just like phone number is displayed. I want ask that is it possible to do this using Java List ?

Comment: When I Click on OK button it is replacing first email with new one and it is not adding to below it. It is because of this code person.setEmail(email.getEmail());

Comment: You are never adding a new emailLineLayout to your emailLayout when buttonClick() is called (I don't know what is happening in refreshEmailList())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a new "emailLineLayout" everytime you click the add button and confirm the action, you need to call **addComponents** within your **dialogConfirmed** method.

```
@Override
public void dialogConfirmed(Person email)
{ 
    GridLayout emailLineLayout = new GridLayout(3, 1);

    // adding components to the GridLayout
    ...

    person.setEmail(email.getEmail());
    emailLayout.addComponent(emailLineLayout);      
}
```

You should also not add an "emailLineLayout" when initializing the "emailLayout".

```
emailLayout.addComponent(emailButton);
```

PS: You have created the "emailLineLayout" only once. You need a new instance of the GridLayout each time you want to add a new email.